Books on thin film characterization?
I'm looking for comprehensive books or resources specifically focused on thin film characterization techniques, particularly with an emphasis on electrical response measurements. While I've consulted articles like this review on the four-probe method and this guide on X-ray diffraction, I’m hoping to find books that provide a more focused overview comparing various techniques used for material characterization but detailing how they are used to probe to thin films and nanostructures.
I would especially appreciate recommendations that delve into the unique challenges presented by 2D thin films and heterostructures, such as surface effects or interface phenomena, and offer a critical analysis of electric response methods like four-point probe, Hall effect measurements, magnetoconductance or impedance spectroscopy.
Advanced resources that provide both theoretical background and practical insights are particularly welcome.

My first reaction was it sounds like you need a book on characterizing objects. You can then just apply it to very thin objects. The topic might be a bit broad.

I disagree. . The methods for 3D objects can’t simply be scaled down to fit thin films. Thin films and nanostructures exhibit unique surface and interface phenomena that do not manifest on bulk materials - such as quantum confinement, surface effects, and interface properties. This often means thin films require more directed characterization methods. I'm looking for resources that specifically address these challenges, particularly in electrical response measurements(magneto-resistance, thermopower, etc.). I recognize your point about the question otherwise being to wide, and corrected it
